# Saving Locally Array of Custom Class in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, xcode, class, swift3, local

I'm trying to save locally Array of Custom Class called Lokacija (English: Location) in xCode 8, Swift 3.

I tried saving it with UserDefault, but unfortunately it doesn't work with custom classes. So i found this article: http://ioscake.com/how-to-archive-and-unarchive-custom-objects-in-swift-or-how-to-save-custom-object-to-nsuserdefaults-in-swift.html. I tried both solutions, but none of them worked for me. BTW Article was written in Swift 2.x, and as I said I am using Swift 3, so I had to translate it.

I firstly tried this:

```
    class Lokacija: NSObject, NSCoding {

        var _name : String
        var _address : String
        var _long : Double
        var _lat : Double

        init(name : String, address : String, lat : Double, long : Double) {
            _name = name
            _address = address
            _lat = lat
            _long = long
            //day month year
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            print("ENCODINGGG!!!")
            aCoder.encode(_name, forKey: "name")
            aCoder.encode(_address, forKey: "address")
            aCoder.encode(_long, forKey: "long")
            aCoder.encode(_lat, forKey: "lat")
        }
    }


//in custom .swift "Utils"

static func saveLocations(lokacije: [Lokacija]) {
    let dataBlob = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: lokacije)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(dataBlob, forKey: "lista")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

static func loadLocations() -> [Lokacija]? {
    guard let decodedDataBlob = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lista") as? Data, let loadedLocations = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedDataBlob) as? [Lokacija] else {
        return nil
    }

    return loadedLocations
}


    //on action
lista.append(selectedLoc)
Utils.saveLocations(lokacije: lista)

//in view did load
    if let listaBase = Utils.loadLocations() {
        lista = listaBase
        self.plannerTable.reloadData()
        print(listaBase.count)
        print(lista.count)
    } else {
        print("PATKA MOREEE!!!")
    }
```

Problem was that it didn't write anything in listaBase, it was empty.
Then I tried second solution:

```
class Lokacija: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var _name : String
    var _address : String
    var _long : Double
    var _lat : Double

    init(name : String, address : String, lat : Double, long : Double) {
        _name = name
        _address = address
        _lat = lat
        _long = long
        //day month year
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        print("ENCODINGGG!!!")
        aCoder.encode(_name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(_address, forKey: "address")
        aCoder.encode(_long, forKey: "long")
        aCoder.encode(_lat, forKey: "lat")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        print("DECODEDDD!!!")
        guard let unName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String, let unAddress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as? String, let unLong = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "long") as? Double, let unLat = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lat") as? Double
            else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(name: unName, address: unAddress, lat: unLat, long: unLong)
    }

    private class func getFileUrl() -> NSURL {

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: (.documentDirectory), in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("lista")

        return archiveURL as NSURL
    }

    class func saveLocations(locations: [Lokacija]){

        let success = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(locations, toFile: Lokacija.getFileUrl().path!)
        if !success {
            print("failed to save")
        }

    }

    class func loadLocations() -> [Lokacija] {

        if let locBase = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Lokacija.getFileUrl().path!) as? [Lokacija] {
            return locBase
        }
        print("NIL")
        return [Lokacija]()
    }

}


//on action
    lista.append(selectedLoc)
    Lokacija.saveLocations(locations: lista)

    //on view did load      
    if Lokacija.loadLocations() != nil {
    let retrivedLocations = Lokacija.loadLocations()
    lista = retrivedLocations
    self.plannerTable.reloadData()
    print(retrivedLocations.count)
    print(lista.count)
}
else {
    print("FAILL!!!")
}
```

And I got exactly the same problem.

Comment: Unrelated but the `guard` statement in the `init?(coder` method is pointless because all properties are clearly encoded as non-optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's problem with the way you're decoding the `Double` values. Use following code for your decoding initializer, it will work:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    print("DECODEDDD!!!")
    guard let unName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String, let unAddress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as? String else {
            return nil
    }

    let unLong = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "long")
    let unLat = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "lat")
    self.init(name: unName, address: unAddress, lat: unLat, long: unLong)
}
```